# How would I write a regular expression that captures A23 but not A 23

Tags: regex, pcre

How would I write a regular expression that does the following:

```
Given:  A23+    returns   A23+
Given:  A 23+   returns   23+
Given:  A.rg23- returns   A.rg23-
Given:  A .rg23- returns  .rg23-
```

Is this best accomplished via a positive lookahead or would the `[^ ]` be able to achieve this?

Comment: @anubhava I'm using pcre.

Comment: What is your current regex?

Comment: I would try something like `([^ ]+)$`

Comment: @anubhava here's what I have, its not working too well: https://regex101.com/r/aD4tT5/1

Comment: @Lashane or `(\S+)$`

Comment: What are you trying to capture? Won't just `\bA\d+` work for you?

Comment: @anubhava  basically if there is a space after the capital A, I would to ignore the A and the space and capture everything else.  But if there is no space after the A I want to include the A in the capture.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> sically if there is a space after the capital A, I would to ignore the A and the space and capture everything else. But if there is no space after the A I want to include the A in the capture.

You can try this regex in PCRE using match reset `\K`:

```
\bA(?: \K)?\S+
```

`\K` resets the starting point of the reported match. Any previously consumed characters are no longer included in the final match. So in this case if there is a space after `A` then `\K` resets matched information thus allowing us to capture whatever comes after it i.e. `\S+`.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/wQ8yV5/1)

Comment: I'm not familiar with match reset K. Thank you.

Comment: `\K` resets the starting point of the reported match. Any previously consumed characters are no longer included in the final match

Comment: Yes it matches correctly, but its not capturing or returning the match. https://regex101.com/r/wQ8yV5/2

Comment: regex101 is for demo purpose only and in my demo link you can see correct matches highlighted. You shouldn't use any captured group as suggested in my code also.

Answer (score 1):

This is another way of doing it.

```
/(?:A )(\S+)|(A\S+)/g
```

Produces the correct matches on regex101.com.