# Positive lookbehind vs match reset (\K) regex feature

Tags: php, python, ruby, regex, perl

I just learned about the [apparently undocumented](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Regexp.html#class-Regexp-label-Anchors) `\K` behavior in Ruby regex (thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35092157/513951) by [anubhava](https://stackoverflow.com/users/548225/anubhava)). This feature (possibly named *Keep*?) also exists in PHP, Perl, and Python regex flavors. It is described elsewhere as "*drops what was matched so far from the match to be returned*."

```
"abc".match(/ab\Kc/)     # matches "c"
```

Is this behavior identical to the positive lookbehind marker as used below?

```
"abc".match(/(?<=ab)c/)  # matches "c"
```

If not, what differences do the two exhibit?

Comment: One difference is, that the lookbehind does not consume characters. See this example [with lookbehind](https://regex101.com/r/gE8fF3/1) vs this  [with use of \K](https://regex101.com/r/jW2sM0/1).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's easier to see the difference between `\K` and `(?<=...)` with the [`String#scan`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-scan) method.

A lookbehind is a zero-width assertion that doesn't consume characters and that is tested (backwards) from the current position:

```
> "abcdefg".scan(/(?<=.)./)
=> ["b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g"]
```

The "keep" feature `\K` *(that isn't an anchor)* defines a position in the pattern where all that was matched so far by the pattern on the left is removed from the match result. But all characters matched before the `\K` are *consumed*, they just don't appear in the result:

```
> "abcdefg".scan(/.\K./)
=> ["b", "d", "f"]
```

The behaviour is the same as without `\K`:

```
> "abcdefg".scan(/../)
=> ["ab", "cd", "ef"]
```

except that the characters before the `\K` are removed from the result.

One interesting use of `\K` is to emulate a variable-length lookbehind, which is not allowed in Ruby *(the same for PHP and Perl)*, or to avoid the creation of a unique capture group. For example `(?<=a.*)f.` can be implemented using `\K`:

```
> "abcdefg".match(/a.*\Kf./)
=> #<MatchData "fg">
```

An alternative way would be to write `/a.*(f.)/`, but the `\K` avoids the need to create a capture group.

Note that the `\K` feature also exists in the python [regex](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex) module, even this one allows variable-length lookbehinds.

Comment: I don't know about Ruby, but `\K` is faster than `(?<=...)` in Perl. /// One normally uses `\K` specifically to avoid having to use a capture group, so it's weird that you would suggest the opposite.

Answer (score 2):

After answering [this other question and including a metaphor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76319854/2943403), I was asked to post an answer on this canonical page.

While refining a given regex, I endeavor to optimize the pattern by a simple hierarchy. Accuracy, then Efficiency, then Readabilty, then Brevity.  Lower order criteria are typically irrelevant to consider when a higher order criteria is imperfect/suboptimal.

---

Please allow me to simplify an already simplified task in the asked question. Instead of matching `c`, let's make one or more zero-width matches with PHP and compare `/a\K/` versus `/(?<=a)/` which both return the same result.

1. While comparing the two pattern designs for this simple demonstration, the Accuracy is identical.
2. Efficiency is where a clear winner and loser is determined.

   ```
   $string = 'abcbacbacbabcbabcbabcccbbaaabacbabbcacbabca';

   $regex1 = '/a\K/'; // 14 matches, 42 steps https://regex101.com/r/j4Jrrj/1

   $regex2 = '/(?<=a)/'; // 14 matches, 167 steps https://regex101.com/r/JuZJDE/1
   ```

Here's why: With `$regex2`, every step that the regex engine takes (each character in the string traversed), it has to turn around and check for a possible `a`.  Conversely, `$regex1` marches swiftly through the characters (looking nowhere but most immediate character), if it encounters an `a`, then a match is made and it doesn't need to look around. As a general tip, lookarounds (and capture groups) can lead to losses in efficiency -- its worth running some tests to see how small tweaks may effect your pattern efficiency.

---

A common scenario is to split a string without consuming any characters.
Splitting `oneTwoThreeFourFiveSix` between a lowercase letter then an uppercase letter, using `preg_split()` can be done with:

1. "look both ways" - `/(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])/` will take 70 steps on the 22-character string (because it needs to look one or both ways at every position).
2. "match any lower, release, lookahead" - `/[a-z]\K(?=[A-Z])/` will take 78 steps (because of the volume of lowercase letters and then take 2 subsequent actions).
3. "match consecutive lowers, release, lookahead" - `/[a-z]+\K(?=[A-Z])/` will take 41 steps (because it only takes additional actions on the last lower).

Of course: `preg_match()` could traverse the string with `/(?:^|[A-Z])[a-z]*/` in 38 steps, but that may be a different discussion on Accuracy in the context of a real project.

---

When we stop asking the regex engine to stop at every character, the competition can tighten up.

```
   $string = 'abcbacbacbabcbabcbabcccbbaaabacbabbcacbabca';

   $regex1 = '/ab\Kc/'; // 5 matches, 45 steps https://regex101.com/r/j4Jrrj/2

   $regex2 = '/(?<=ab)c/'; // 5 matches, 44 steps https://regex101.com/r/JuZJDE/2
```

`$regex1` traverses the string until it finds an `a`, then a `b`, then a `c`.
`$regex2` traverses the string until it finds a `c`, then looks behind for a `b`, then an `a`.

The sample string contains `a` 14x, `c` 24x, `ab` 7x, and `bc` 6x.
The character existence and order has a direct impact on step count.
For the record, `/abc/` requires only 38 steps, so the `\K` costs 7 steps (for each `ab` matched), but `/ab(c)/` costs more -- 50 steps.

---

And to show a lookbehind outperform `\K`, search for semicolons which occur after a digit in `Price: $5666;Weight: 7145;Height: 420;Width: 411;`.
Because digits occur far more frequently than semicolons, `/(?<=\d);/` takes 20 steps and `/\d\K;/` takes 46 steps.

### The takeaway

Asking the regex engine to take an action on every position in a string is an inefficient task -- even if you prefer the readability.

Beyond that, it is often the frequency and order of characters which determine the regex engines performance.