# Add "e" after specified consonants if not already followed by a vowel

Tags: php, regex, replace

I am trying to use `str_replace()` to replace consonants which are not followed by a vowel with the consonant then an `e`. So, `lb` should become `leb`.

Conversely, a string like `la` should not become `lea`, but remain `la` because the `l` is followed by a vowel.

```
$phrase = "ol sonf"; 
$key = ["l", "n", "s" ,"f"];
$replace = ["le","ne","se","fe"];

$newPhrase = str_replace($key, $replace, $phrase);

echo $phrase;
echo "</br></br></br>";
echo $newPhrase;
```

results: **ol sonf =  ole seonefe**

but should be:

**ol sonf = ole sonefe**

**s** is a consonant but as it is next to a vowel **so** -- in this case it should not be replaced, same rule should be applied to all vowels **A, E, I, O, U**.

I mean it should only apply `e` to **silent consonants**.

Comment: Sounds like `preg_replace()` would be more appropriate

Comment: do you know how to only apply this rule to `silent consonants` ?

Comment: “_s_ is a consonant but as it is next to a vowel _so_” - by that do you mean that _seo_ should not be changed, because of the _o_ which follows _se_?

Comment: Why `ole` for `ol`? `l` has a vowel before it. So, it should be fine since you said _to replace consonants which are not next to vowels_

Comment: @nic I have made the English in the body more precise -- the vowel must come after the consonant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Match an `f`, `l`, `n`, or `s`.
- Forget that matched letter with `\K`.
- Qualify the match if the next letter not a vowel.
- Replace the empty match with `e` (effectively add the `e` on that position)

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/CGa56))

```
$phrase = "ol sonf";
echo preg_replace('/[flns]\K(?![aeiou])/', 'e', $phrase);
// ole sonefe
```

I recommend matching the listed consonant then restarting the fullstring match versus using a lookbehind (`/(?<=[flns])(?![aeiou])/`) as a matter of pattern efficiency.  The regex engine can traverse the input string roughly 3x faster using my match&release technique versus making a lookbehind at every character position in the string.

There are many examples on Stack Overflow of contributors implementing a zero-width match with only a lookbehind followed by a lookahead.  When you see them, remember this page.  In virtually all cases, you will be able to optimize the pattern by replacing the lookbehind with a match&release subpattern.

---

Maybe a metaphor will help to crystalize the approach. Imagine you are running a marathon and want to know if chewing gum becomes stuck to the bottom of your shoe.

- The lookbehind&lookahead pattern is like checking the bottom of each your shoe every time you take a step toward the finish line (of a marathon!).
- Due to your sense of sight and touch, you will be able to identify when you step on a wad of chewing gum.  When you sense that there is reason to check your shoe for lodged debris, THEN you actually bend your leg to be able to check your sole. This is how the match&lookahead works. It is very sensible to not check your shoe after every step.

<sub>*note: I have no idea why you are doing this or even what language this is.</sub>

Comment: You can even "play" the debugger to watch how [at every character position of the sample string, a lookbehind is performed](https://regex101.com/r/VbdYVq/1/debugger).  With my pattern, [the regex engine only looks ahead when it matches an `f`, `l`, `n`, or `s`](https://regex101.com/r/VbdYVq/2/debugger).

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot! about  the language it's enoquian pronunciation, to make easier to portuguese speakers, some rules to portuguese, is add a E on silent consonants, there are also other rules for others letters like z = zod and so on but this is easier to implement , so to automate the transcription process I made this code, thank you.

Comment: Community, I'd love to hear the justification for the no-comment dv.

Answer (score 2):

Let's allow ourselves a bit of madness by using the [transliterator of intl](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.transliterator.php):

```
$phrase = 'ol sonf';

$tsl = \Transliterator::createFromRules('([f l n s]) } [^ a e i o u] > $1 e');

echo $tsl->transliterate($phrase);
```

Note that the syntax of this rule is very similar to a regex pattern:

- the capture group: use of round brackets, and of a reference in the replacement part
- the right context `}` that acts like a lookahead
- character sets, similar to character classes with free-spacing

But there's a subtle difference in the negated character set, this one contains the [Æther](https://unicode-org.github.io/icu/userguide/transforms/general/rules.html#%C3%A6ther) that matches the end of the string.